# How to optimize a search between dates in a WP Query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In the posts I have a date field and a start and end date range. I need to query if it matches date or if it matches between the dates in the range. This Query works, but how can I optimize it to be faster?

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => array('post'),
'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
'posts_per_page' => 20,
'paged'          => 1,
'meta_query'     => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'this_day',
        'value' => $startday,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'date_start',
            'value' => $endday,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'date_end',
            'value' => $startday,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
    )
));

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'this_day' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '20220701' ) OR ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'date_start' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) <= '20220701' ) AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'date_end' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) >= '20220701' ) ) ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it works and should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Also, what do you mean "faster"?

Comment: I use meta_query with two conditionals and it takes a long time to load the data, I think there is surely a better way to request that query between the dates.

Comment: For help with MySQL queries, please provide the generated SQL statement and `SHOW CREATE TABLE.